# Can placement new (expression) throw if the constructor of the object is noexcept?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, placement-new, noexcept

```
template <class T>
struct Obj {
  // Plain Old Data for T
  using InternalPod = typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), std::alignment_of<T>::value>::type;

  InternalPod value_pod_;

  template<class... Args>
  Obj(Args&&... args) { // my constructor
    // placement new: construct the value in the statically allocated space
    new (&value_pod_) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...); // <- can this whole expression throw if the constructor of T doesn’t throw?
  }
}
```

*Normal* `new` can throw if the allocation fails or if the construction fails (correct me if there are other cases), but since placement new doesn’t allocate any space, can the new expression throw if the constructor of `T` doesn’t throw?

I.e. is the following `noexcept` specification correct and safe?

```
Obj(Args&&... args) noexcept(noexcept(T(std::forward<Args>(args)...))) {
  new (&value_pod_) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: All placement-`operator new` does is return the pointer it is passed, so no, placement new itself can't throw.

Comment: @Simple: Placement new certainly can throw, but only if the object being constructed throws in its constructor.

Comment: @Mankarse right, the `new` expression as a whole can, but the `operator new` doesn't.

Comment: I am interested in the expression as a whole

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify that.

Comment: @bolov well as said placement-`operator new` never throws, so the only thing that *can* throw is the constructor.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The placement `new` from `<new>` is declared to be `noexcept` according to 18.6 [support.dynamic] paragraph 1:

> ... `void* operator new (std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept;` ...

When using a `new` expression the system does exactly two things:

1. It calls the appropriate version of the `operator new()` to obtain memory. If memory allocation fails it should throw `std::bad_alloc` for an `operator new()` without a `noexcept` qualification and return `nullptr` otherwise.
2. If a non-`nullptr` is returned, the expression then calls the constructor of the type in the `new` expression. If this construction fails with an exception, the `operator delete()` matching the called `operator new()` is called with the result from that `operator new()`.

Since memory allocation can't fail, the only option to get an exception is from the constructor of the type.

Comment: I guess the question is if the new expression does anything else that can throw beyond calling the constructor

Comment: The only things calling placement new does is call the above `operator new()` followed by calling the constructor of the object in the `new` expression (and it would call a matching `operator delete()` if the construction throws an exception).

Comment: The placement new expression also checks the address returned by `operator new` against `nullptr` before calling the constructor. It won't make a difference in this case, of course, but it's good to remember.

Comment: What if the actual arguments passed to `Obj<T>::Obj` require a user defined conversion, which might throw?

Comment: @JamesKanze then the constructor throws… I think

Comment: @bolov Then the conversion operator throws.